# Spring RabbitMq - Queue created event listener

Tags: java, spring, events, listener, spring-rabbit

I would like to know if there are any events published when the `queue` is actually physically created in `Rabbitmq` via `Spring Api`.

The reason I am asking is somehow we have race condition. The subscription for `queue` is somehow usually taking longer and while the subscription is happening already a message is sent to this queue from BE and as a result queue is not present in `Rabbitmq` and the message is lost and never reaches FE.

Sorry I cannot provide any code as such, because it wont make much sense by putting a small piece of code.

But I am pretty sure, problem is because of kind of race condition, message to the queue is being sent even before its created. So if there is some `event listener` I could listen after the queue is created, I could move my logic to this method.

Here is some piece of code,

`stomp-client.js`

```
 stompClient.subscribe(destination, function(msg) {});
```

`WebsocketConnectionListener.java`

```
@EventListener
public void handleWebSocketSessionSubscribeEvent(final SessionSubscribeEvent event) {

 // here I think this event is fired before the queue is actual created
 // this event is fired when u send subscription from stomp-client.js

 ...
 ...
 ...

 // trying to send message to this subscribed queue

 simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend(TOPIC_PREFIX + destination, data, headers);
 // now this message is lost as sometimes the queue creation takes longer.
 // unfortunately I want to move the convert and send method, when I could listen to queue created event.

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no event published but you can add a second `ConnectionListener` to the `CachingConnectionFactory`. If you make sure it is added after the `RabbitAdmin` you can be sure that the `onCreate()` method will be called after the admin has declared all the exchanges, queues, bindings.

See `AbstractConnectionFactory.addConnectionListener`.

Comment: I got your point, but not all my queues are created on server startup. Most of the queues are created dynamically by sending subscription from front end. And as per my understanding this newly created listener wont get notified for every queue that u create/subscribe later or am I wrong.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean - if you are creating the queues dynamically yourself then you will know that they are created - these operations are blocking - not asynchronous - use `RabbitAdmin.declareQueue(queue)`.